# Virtual Sticks not working

Tags: android, simulator, dji-sdk

I am unable to use the virtual sticks in [Mobile-SDK-Android sample code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) and [Android-SimultorDemo](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-SimulatorDemo) with the simulator. I am able to auto takeoff and auto land the drone in the simulator but cannot move the drone with virtual joysticks. I can move the drone in the simulator with the help of RC. I followed the tutorial at [here](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/SimulatorDemo.html). Am I supposed to change some mode or some type with the RC or drone? The problem is described in more detail in [here](http://forum.dev.dji.com/thread-32729-1-1.html)(by someone else).

I am using mavic pro.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to enable the virtual stick mode before hand?
you can do so by calling setVirtualStickModeEnabled in the flightcontroller object.

More info:
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_setvirtualstickmodeenabled_inline